# How to save chart image to a PDF with good resolution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, stream, itext

```
 using (MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream())
 {
    Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)));
    pdfDoc.Add(p2);

    pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));
    pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));

    PieChart.SaveImage(stream1, ChartImageFormat.Png);
    iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream1.GetBuffer());
    chartImage1.ScalePercent(75f); chartImage1.SpacingBefore = 100f;

    chartImage1.SpacingAfter = 110f;
    pdfDoc.Add(chartImage1); pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));// pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n")); pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));
    //byte[] bytes1 = stream.ToArray();
 }
```

C# print the Barchart image with poor resolution, and this Barchart has a lot of data so user will not be able to read it, so I need another good way to do it

Thank you